# How to configure multiple root for nginx?

Tags: nginx

```
location ~ {
            root /var/www/static1/;
            root /var/www/static2/;
        }
```

I tried the above,so that when `/name.gif` is requested ,if `/var/www/static1/name.gif` exists, then just use it as is;but if there isn't such a file,try to see if there's `/var/www/static2/name.gif`, is it possible to configure nginx this way?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you're using nginx 0.7.24(?) or later, you can accomplish this with try_files:

```
location / {
    root /var/www;
    try_files /static1$uri /static2$uri =404;
}
```

Normally, having root inside location / is incorrect, but in this specific case, I don't think you want to set /var/www as your general root in case you end up adding other locations.

Comment: >"Normally, having root inside location / is incorrect" -- What's the correct way to configure this?

Comment: it is best practice to have root be in the server {} block, but I don't think this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain your exact configuration is not possible. To serve from multiple roots, you'd need to alias one root into your URL structure, something like this:

```
location  /images/ {
  alias  /path/to/images;
}
```

Comment: @ErikA,thanks for your reply!But seems this only works for specific requests,right?

Comment: Yes, it would be invoked for requests to /images/.

Comment: @ErikA,but I want it to check both directories if there's no such file under one of them...

Comment: Or apart from nginx,is it possible to configure linux so that `/var/www/static` will merge both `/var/www/static1` and `/var/www/static2`?

Comment: No it is not. Is there a reason you just can't manually merge the two directories? The only reason I'd think you wouldn't be able to do that is if there were possible filename collisions, but in that case, how would nginx know which file to serve anyway? Seems like you're trying to solve this problem the wrong way perhaps.

Comment: @ErikA, in my specific case,filename collisions are manually dealt with,so no need to consider this case:)